# Temperature of a metal plate throughout the day

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I analysed the thermal behaviour of a metal plate (lying on an insulating surface) when the sun shines on it. I obtained a differential equation that I don't know how to solve. So the problem:
The flux density solar radiation onto the plate varies throughout the day as
$$
j=j_{\ast} \cdot \sin((\frac{t}{t_0}\pi)
$$
Where $t_0$ is the length of the day and $j_*=1361\frac{W}{m^2}$ is the solar constant.
The heat transfer inside the plate is very fast - the temperature is always the same at all points inside the plate. The thickness of the plate is $h$, the product of its density and specific heat capacity will be denoted by $C=c_{spec}\cdot \rho$. The starting temperature (in the morning) is $T_0$ and the Stefan-Boltzmann constant is $\sigma$. The plate only radiates on one side and only absorbs radiation on that same side.
What I obtained is:
$$
dT=\frac{1}{hC}(j_*\sin(\frac{t}{t_0}\pi)-\sigma T^4) dt
$$
Is this analytically solvable? If yes, how? If not, what approximation technique would yield the best results?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: This is a Chini's Equation, with $n=4$. I doubt there is a way to solve this analytically. However, there are ways to get a numerical result, depending on why you need it. 
Maybe useful? : https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FChini

Comment: It is known that if the Chini invariant
$$
C=f(t)^{-n-1}h(t)^{-2n+1}(f(t)
dh(t)/dt-h(t)df(t)/dt+n f(t)g(t)h(t))^n n^{-n}
$$
is independent of $t$, there is a straightforward recipe 
for solving the equation. Check, I think Kamke's book.